# Codeigniter in PHPStorm

Tags: codeigniter

I need to know if any special configuration in the ide PhpStorm to use CodeIgniter . I'm having problems permission to access session variables and writing temporary files . The server is XAMPP local for IOS

Error from comment

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Unknown: Failed
>   to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting
>   of session.save_path is correct (/Applications/temp/) Filename:
>   Unknown Line Number: 0 Backtrace: A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning Message: Unknown:
>   open(/Applications/temp//sess_acelvldc0c60ti1pj13fmil6t6, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13) Filename: Unknown Line Number: 0
>   Backtrace

Comment: Please provide specific examples of the problems you are encountering with code examples where possible.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/Applications/temp/)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Unknown: open(/Applications/temp//sess_acelvldc0c60ti1pj13fmil6t6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Comment: i've used phpstorm with codeigniter 2 and 3 with no issues. the new phpstorm 10 beta works really well. recent info about autocomplete and codeigniter here http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63641.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use session files on codeigniter 3

Where ever you save your file example:

```
application

application > temp
```

Then on your config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'temp/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Make sure the sess_save_path has `/`at end.

Also make sure you have set temp folder permissions to chmod 0700 You need set permission for your var directory

Comment: Why the down vote? Please explain. The Answer worked for the OP